# Move ADL Friend Declaration

Tags: c++

Consider the following class:

```
template<class a>
class c
{
public:
    int x = 0;
    // not really templated
    friend constexpr auto operator +( int const left,
                                      c const & a ) noexcept
    {
        return c{ left + x };
    }
};
```

How does one move the function body without declaring it in the outer scope? e.g. pseudo:

```
template<class a>
friend constexpr auto c<a>::operator +( int const left,
                                        c const & a ) noexcept
{
    return c{ left + x };
}
```

Comment: This syntax is impossible for  friend.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet of OP:

```
class c
{
public:
    int x = 0;
    friend constexpr auto operator +( int const left,
                                      c const & a ) noexcept
    {
        return c{ left + x };
    }
};
```

It shows a free function (operator) that is inline defined in `class c` as `friend`.
This is not a member function of `class c` although it may look so on the first glance.
(If it would be a member function it would be a ternary operator+ but there doesn't exist one in C++ nor can it be overloaded.)

The second snippet of OP:

```
friend constexpr auto c::operator +( int const left,
                                     c const & a ) noexcept
{
    return c{ left + x };
}
```

It is wrong for two reasons:

1. `friend` doesn't make sense. (`friend` to what?)
2. If it's a free function - scope `c::` doesn't make sense.

**The friendship of functions *cannot* be declared outside of the resp. class.**

If this would be allowed everybody could declare friendship of functions everywhere which accesses the `private` members of classes. This would make the sense of `private` members somehow useless.

(Imagine a safe with an electronic lock and a key pad where the password is written on the door.)

[image: A somehow useless safe]

(Original image by [Binarysequence](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Binarysequence) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=41396220))

Nevertheless, `friend` functions (and operators) *can be defined* non-inline, of course.

The following sample shows how:

```
#include <iostream>

// forward declaration of class c
class c;

// forward declaration of operator +
constexpr auto operator+(int, c const&) noexcept;

// the class c
class c {
  // make operator + a friend to grant access to private members
  friend constexpr auto operator+(int, c const&) noexcept;
  
  private:
    int x;
  
  public:
    c() = default;
    constexpr c(int x): x(x) { }
    
    int get() const { return x; }
};

// the operator +
constexpr auto operator+(int lhs, c const &rhs) noexcept
{
  return c(lhs + rhs.x);
}

// show it in action:

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(c a(123));
  DEBUG(std::cout << (234 + a).get() << '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
c a(123);
std::cout << (234 + a).get() << '\n';
357
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f3153a62ff4cd4c)

---

This is similar when applied to templates (although the syntax is a bit more tricky):

```
#include <iostream>

// forward declaration of class c
template <typename T>
class c;

// forward declaration of operator +
template <typename T>
constexpr auto operator+(int, c<T> const&) noexcept;

// the class c
template <typename T>
class c {
  friend constexpr auto operator+<>(int, c<T> const&) noexcept;
  
  private:
    T x;
  
  public:
    c() = default;
    constexpr c(T x): x(x) { }
    
    int get() const { return x; }
};

// the operator +
template <typename T>
constexpr auto operator+(int lhs, c<T> const &rhs) noexcept
{
  return c(lhs + rhs.x);
}

// show it in action:

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(c<int> a(123));
  DEBUG(std::cout << (234 + a).get() << '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
c<int> a(123);
std::cout << (234 + a).get() << '\n';
357
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4239ad36460e2fd)

---

More about inline friend functions:

- [SO: **friend AND inline method, what's the point ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381164/7478597)
- [SO: **c++ implementing friend/inline functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147808/7478597) (similar question)
- [SO: **Nonmember friend function is always inline**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40793784/7478597) (similar question)

Comment: This is a good answer explaining how friend operators work but inlining a friend function is different from declaring it in the outer scope. I'll edit my question to show why and what problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @superdeveloper I just recalled [cppreference.com - Template friend operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators). I'm afraid what you want is not allowed nor possible.

Comment: @superdeveloper I made a modified [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4239ad36460e2fd) but I'm not quite sure whether this is what you are looking for. I remember that I once took part in a Q/A about making a function template a friend of a class whereby only the corresponding template instances with equal type should have friendship. However, I cannot find it anymore... :-(

Comment: I see; so the secret is to make it `operator +<>`. This is great information.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to define the function in a **source** file such that its out-of-class declaration is not visible to (other) clients.  (You would not be able to have its return type be deduced in that case.)  In C++20, you can do something very similar by not **exporting** the friend from a module.

It has been suggested that what you want should be achievable with a differently **qualified** definition:

```
constexpr auto ::operator +( int const left,
                             c const & a ) noexcept
{
    return c{ left + x };
}
```

The otherwise redundant scope resolution operator would cause the definition to “not count” for name lookup, but GCC and Clang currently give it other interpretations: Clang does let ordinary lookup find the function (and issues a warning in the global scope case), while GCC rejects it entirely.